# Caminho para imagem em JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, img

Preciso exibir uma imagem dentro da tag `img`.

É um projeto web, rodando no Tomcat e Ubuntu Mate. Eu salvo em banco como String o caminho de onde está a imagem:

```
"/opt/imagens/img.png"
```

Para exibir, coloco está desta forma

```
<img src="<%=urlImg.getUrl()%>" >
```

`urlImg.getUrl()` retorna `"/opt/imagens/img.png"`

A imagem não aparece, alguém, por gentileza, saberia me explicar o que está errado e o que deve ser feito para corrigir?

Comment: Se foi salvo no banco como `/opt/imagens/img.png` faz todo sentido exibir `/opt/imagens/img.png`, você tem que considerar qual é o caminho/rota para o servidor HTTP, você deve ter criado o "mapeamento" para os arquivos estáticos, não?

Comment: Guilherme, não fiz mapeamento, o que seria isso? Essa pasta está fora do projeto, é uma pasta de sistema operacional mesmo.

Comment: você sabe apontar a pasta imagens para uma rota nos Hosts do TomCat? Vou tentar postar uma resposta com exemplo, talvez ajude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado a todos, inclusive Guilherme pela atenção.

A solução encontrada foi gerar uma string com os bytes da imagem e exibir diretamente.

O método que criei para retornar a string, a partir do arquivo de imagem:

```
public static String convertPngToByteString(String path) {
        String img = "";
        try{
            File imagem = new File(path);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(imagem);
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", bos);
            bi.flush();
            byte[] imageInByte = bos.toByteArray();
            bos.close();
            img = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByte);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        return img;
    }
```

Com esse método, no JSP exibo da seguinte forma:

```
<img src="<%="data:image/png;Base64,"+ImagemUtil.convertPngToByteString(urlImg.getUrl())%>" width="213" height="160" id="imgFoto" />
```

Pode não ser a melhor forma, mas faz o que preciso. =)

Answer (score 0):

Não entendo muito de Tomcat, mas creio que em **sua aplicação** exista o `server.xml`, nele deve haver um local escrito algo como:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" ...>

...

</Host>
```

Então dentro você poderia adicionar:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" ...>

    <Context docBase="/opt/imagens" path="/imagens" />

    ...

</Host>
```

> Creio que tenha que reiniciar o teu webapp

Então após reiniciar as imagens estão acessiveis via o caminho HTTP, algo como:

```
 http://localhost/imagens/1.jpg
```

Comment: No caso, eu estava procurando algo relacionado a Servlets. Não posso alterar configurações do tomcat. Nem que eu tenha que copiar a imagem para alguma pasta dentro da aplicação, algo assim...

Comment: @MayconStanguine tem sim como fazer direto pelo servelets, vou tentar criar uma explicação sobre o assunto, talvez nem precise alterar nada.

Comment: Obrigado, ficarei no aguardo de sua explicação.